# Autoit: How to delete a printer based on its IP address?

Tags: printing, scripting, autoit

I am creating an AutoIt application to install network printers. However, I need a way to check for or delete a printer if it is already installed. I am using Prnmngr.vbs to check for names:

```
RunWait (@ComSpec & ' /c Cscript "' & $Prnmngr & '" -d -p "' & $printerName & '"', "", @SW_HIDE)
```

However, the name of any particular printer can vary from computer to computer. Is there a way I can search by IP address and thus get the name as installed on the computer?

Comment: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/155485-printers-management-with-wmi/?p=1123616